# I'm getting a "The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock" error

Tags: cocoapods

I'm getting a "The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock" error.  I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Cocoapods several times to no success.  It looks like the install worked as when I open the workspace file I have two projects that appear, the one I built and one named "Pods".  And under the "Pods" project when I select the Target, I see that the environment variables are there, "Pods_Root" and others.  I think I need to add the "$(inherited)" to my main project, the one I built but I am not sure where.  I am using XCode 8.

Any help would be great as I have tried most of the items I have seend.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769333/xcode-podfile-lock-no-such-file/43772438#43772438

Comment: Thanks.  I have already tried removing and re-installing several times.  It seems like the master or main project is not picking up the variables set for the pods project.  I am not sure how to make the main project see them without adding them in manually.