# Error with pods after cloning the repo

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have downloaded the project from bitbucket. Everything works fine besides one thing. There is a problem with pods.

I'm adding what appeared while I wanted to run the project:

```
diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366549/errorthe-sandbox-is-not-in-sync-with-the-podfile-lock-after-installing-res

Comment: This question may be duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769333/xcode-podfile-lock-no-such-file